# AppConfig.java? trying to make this dynamic not static

Tags: android, dynamic, static, app-config

I would like the end user (android app) to be able to enter an url that points to the host db, currently this works perfectly, however I would like to be able to install several different databases on my hosting account, as it is now I can only install one that points to `/valueTracker/` which I believe is static how would I open this up to be more dynamic?

```
package com.valuetracker;

public class AppConfig {
  public static final boolean debugging = false;

  public static String strSitePrefix = "";
  public static String strServerPrefix = "";

  static {
    if(debugging) {
      strSitePrefix = "/valueTracker/api/";     
    } else {
      strSitePrefix = "/valueTracker/api/";
    }
  }

  enum ErrorCode {
    ERROR_PARSE_MESSAGE,
    ERROR_NETWORK_FAIL
  };
}
```

Comment: Your question is quite vague and confusing. Can you explain in more detail? How is this class being used? What do you mean by install several different databases on my hosting account? How does the user enter the URL's and how are the URL's used?

Comment: the user enters the server URL through a server setting dialog box thru the android app. example www.company.com - that connects to the db on the server www.company.com/valueTracker. say you wanted to download the app and have the db and admin dashboard on a server of your choice the current code wont allow this. I would like to know best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok from what I understand you are looking for the best way to store user entered URL's, which your app will use to access a database.

If the app will only allow the user to have 1 server, the best way is to store the URL in a android Shared Preference. SharedPreferences are basically just settings your app can store values in. A very basic database, and very easy to use. It would look something like:

```
 SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
 prefeditor.putString("user_url", url);
```

If the app is going to support more than 1 URL you should use a database. (You could use the method above and just store multiple shared preferences if there will only be 2 or 3 urls available, but it's hacky and not scalable).

For something simple like storing strings, it will be pretty easy to implement a database solution.
I recommend [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/).

Follow the example code to store a model containing just a string url field. 
On the app startup, load all the URLs from the database, and store them somewhere, like on the Application class, which is a singleton.